# Review / remove the related question section

Tags: discussion, related-questions

I noticed that the questions in the "related questions" list are less and less related to the actual question.

Reading this question ([WPF and C# ComboBox Next Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435147/wpf-and-c-sharp-combobox-next-focus)) gave me this related list:

[image]

The top question is about strings and blatantly unrelated to my actual searched question. That question page does not even contain `string` or `enum`.

In this state, I think it should be better to deactivate - or at least give the users the option to disable it - as it's not giving any productibility advantages.

Comment: The related section also provides some love to questions that might not necessarily receive the love they deserve

Comment: But @WhatsThePoint of a related question if it's not related?

Comment: I downvoted because of _"I'm posting this because this list keeps distracting me as some questions look interesting, and I lose a few minutes because of a click-baiting title."_ I don't see a reason to globally hide the list when it's something you can easily hide yourself with one of the custom CSS add-ons or addblocker.

Comment: @Hille but the questions are related, they all share an x amount of tags with the question you are viewing

Answer (score 5):

While the "related" questions could always be improved, no matter how it was done it would always be hit and miss. No matter if the site was populated using the question titles, tags, content or whatever; in the end many false positives would pop-up with some frecuency.

Currently, as explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309038/348149) by Joel Spolsky, the site is relying on ElasticSearch features to populate the list:

> Things have changed a bit since 2009 :-) We rely heavily on Elasticsearch these days. The "related" questions now come from an [Elasticsearch "More Like This" query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html).
>
> Elastic uses [tf-idf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309038/348149) for most things, which is a standard search algorithm.  >Their particular implementation is [documented here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html).

The main argument for making the feature "optional" seems rather foolish. If you lose time because you get distracted by links, the onus is on you to either work on your self-control, or to implement solutions on your end (as a content blocker of some sort) to help you manage these distractions.

I know that the web can be a mightitly distracting place, not only Stack Overflow.